# How to display a matrix in a descending and ascending form in a JTextArea java with Array.sort?

Tags: java, swing, sorting, jtable

I need to sort the matrix in descending and ascending order but print it as a 1 dimension array.

Currently it sorts in ascending order but only the last row and I don't know how to show all the rows and I don't know how to sort it in a descending way.

```
 public void mostrarMatriz (int matriz[][], int n){
        
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tablaMatriz.getModel();
        model.setRowCount(n);
        model.setColumnCount(n);
       
        for(int i = 0; i < n ; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < n; j++){
                tablaMatriz.setValueAt(matriz[i][j], i, j);
            } 
        }
        for(int[] i: matriz){   
            Arrays.sort(i);
            txtMenor.setText(Arrays.toString(i));
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: is a TextArea there the last row is shown, and I want it to show all the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The loop should append the text, instead of resetting it at each iteration:

```
String text="";
for(int[] i: matriz)
{   
   Arrays.sort(i);
   text+=Arrays.toString(i)+" ";
}
if (!text.isEmpty())
    txtMenor.setText(text.subString(0,text.length()-1));
```

---

Contrary order, just **flip**  it after:

```
Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(matriz)); 
txtX.setText(Arrays.deepToString(matriz));
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason only the last row of the matrix is being shown in the text is because is being overwritten on each iteration for example:

```
// text is being set/overwritten in each iteration of this loop
for(int[] i : matriz) {
    Arrays.sort(i);
    txtMenor.setText(Arrays.toString(i));
}

// You can use append instead
String text = "";
for(int[] i : matriz) {
    Arrays.sort(i);
    text += Arrays.toString(i) + " ";
}
txtMenor.setText(text);
```

To show each row in descending order you will have to sort each array in reverse order before appending it to the text. You can use streams:

```
// You can use append instead
String text = "";
for(int[] i : matriz) {
    int[] sorted = IntStream.of(i)
        .boxed()
        .sorted(Comparator.reverseOrder())
        .mapToInt(a -> a)
        .toArray();
    text += Arrays.toString(sorted) + " ";
}
txtMenor.setText(text);
```